# How do I set up a Python CGI server?

Tags: python, html, windows, http, cgi

I'm running Python 3.2 on Windows. I want to run a simple CGI server on my machine for testing purposes. Here's what I've done so far:

I created a python program with the following code:

```
import http.server
import socketserver
PORT = 8000
Handler = http.server.CGIHTTPRequestHandler
httpd = socketserver.TCPServer(("", PORT), Handler)
httpd.serve_forever()
```

In the same folder, I created "index.html", a simple HTML file. I then ran the program and went to http://localhost:8000/ in my web browser, and the page displayed successfully. Next I made a file called "hello.py" in the same directory, with the following code:

```
import cgi
import cgitb
cgitb.enable()
print("Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8")
print()
print("""<html><body><p>Hello World!</p></body></html>""")
```

Now if I go to http://localhost:8000/hello.py, my web browser displays the full code above instead of just "Hello World!". How do I make python execute the CGI code before serving it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at the [docs for CGIHTTPRequestHandler](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/http.server#http.server.CGIHTTPRequestHandler), which describe how it works out which files are CGI scripts.

Comment: I moved "hello.py" to a folder called "cgi-bin", and when I tried again, I got the following error: `File "C:\Python32\lib\http\server.py", line 1019, in run_cgi` `env['SERVER_NAME'] = self.server.server_name` `AttributeError: 'TCPServer' object has no attribute 'server_name'`

Comment: @dln385: I think you want HTTPServer, rather than the plain TCPServer: http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/http.server#http.server.HTTPServer

Answer (score 2):

Though not officialy deprecated, the `cgi` module is a bit clunky to use; most folks these days are using something else (anything else!)

You can, for instance, use the wsgi interface to write your scripts in a way that can be easily and efficiently served in many http servers.  To get you started, you can even use the builtin `wsgiref` handler.

```
def application(environ, start_response):
    start_response([('content-type', 'text/html;charset=utf-8')])
    return ['<html><body><p>Hello World!</p></body></html>'.encode('utf-8')]
```

And to serve it (possibly in the same file):

```
import wsgiref.simple_server
server = wsgiref.simple_server.make_server('', 8000, application)
server.serve_forever()
```

Answer (score 1):

simplest way to start a cgi server for development is following:

- create a base directory with all your html and other files
- create a subdirectory named `cgi-bin` with all your cgi files
- cd to the base directory
- run `python -m http.server --cgi -b 127.0.0.1 8000`

Now you can connect to http://localhost:8000 and tst your html code with cgi scripts

Answer (score 0):

This is what works for me:

```py
#Just runs a basic Python HTTP web server to host everything in this folder.
import http.server
import functools
import pathlib

port = 8000
launchPath = str(pathlib.Path(__file__).parent.resolve())

Handler = functools.partial(http.server.CGIHTTPRequestHandler, directory = launchPath)

with http.server.HTTPServer(("", port), Handler) as httpd:
  print("Serving files in: " + launchPath)
  print("Port: " + str(port))
  httpd.serve_forever()
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.server.html#http.server.CGIHTTPRequestHandler
https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.server.html#http.server.HTTPServer