# Handle HTML Form Data with Python?

Tags: python, html, forms

I'm trying to use Python and HTML together. What I'm trying to do is create an HTML Form that will submit data to a python file and that python file will then handle the data. But I'm not getting it to work.

Here is my python code:

```
form = cgi.FieldStorage() # instantiate only once!

name = form['Sample Name'].value
```

and this is my HTML code:

```
<form method='POST' action='/functionGen.py'> 
Name: <input type='text' name='Sample Name'> 
<input type='submit' value='Begin Storing'> 
</form>
```

What ends up happening is I just see my python code in the browser, the file doesn't begin handling the data.

What can I do?

Comment: If you're seeing python code in the browser then the problem is your server configuration rather than the code you've posted. What server are you using? Apache?

Comment: It's better to use web frameworks to write webapps on python. Look at [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) which is pretty simple.

Comment: @zvzdhk  I'm not looking to write webapps, I already have a form prepared, I just want to be able to receive the information.

Comment: `What server are you using? Apache?`

Comment: @zvzdhk  I'm not using any server, I'm building this locally on my own computer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should know, that you are getting plain python source document via http protocol now. If you want to use [CGI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Gateway_Interface) mechanism, you should place youre .py in cgi-enabled directory. It means that you need http server.

### related questions

- [How to run Python CGI script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7929848/how-to-run-python-cgi-script)
- [How do I set up a Python CGI server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8156898/how-do-i-set-up-a-python-cgi-server)

Comment: But im running this on my computer, can I not link the two files together so that the submit button in the html form executes the python file and submits data aswell?

Comment: Thanks. To run the CGI server do I have to keep that pyhon file running?

Comment: Server with cgi-support would call scripts by himself